# Windows File History Include/Exclude Order of Precedence?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I am attempting to configure Win 10 Pro File History, without continually backing up stuff I don't want, overflowing by backup device, and want to exclude all of `%UserProfile%\Documents`, except for:

```
%UserProfile%\Documents\visual studio 2015\projects
```

- Simply trying to use the *Add A Folder* button within the *Backup Options* tab in Settings does not work, even though it is present within :

  ```
  %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\config1.xml
  ```

  When looking at the contents of the backup drive, there is no content for the included `projects` sub-directory, even though both the include and exclude are present:

  ```xml
  <UserFolder>C:\Users\<name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects</UserFolder>
  ...
  <FolderExclude Hidden="true">C:\Users\<name>\Documents</FolderExclude>
  ```

Any advice or relevant pointers appreciated.

Comment: Relying on manual changes to the `.xml` configs is problematic - I'm unsure why, but File History has issues when manual changes are made to the `.xml` config _(even if modified while the OS is offline)_, and will often revert or break the manual changes made. I'm unsure if this is a bug or operating as designed _(e.g. without knowing how File History operates on the back end, the `.xml` configs may be dynamically generated from File History's GUI settings)_. I've tried and failed with this method, spending hours trying to find a solution on Microsoft Docs, and never could find one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update XML files.

Go to *Control Panel > File History > Exclude folders*, click the *Add* button
and select the folder to exclude. Repeat as required.

Comment: Please read post. The Add does not work when Exclude is present!

Comment: If I understood right, what you mean is that the added folders don't get backup'ed, and this happens because you added some exclusions. That they are backup'ed successfully if there are no exclusions. Do both these statements seem correct?

Comment: I think so. To be very specific, I would like c:\users\me\documents\visual studio 2015\projects backed up, but _nothing else_ in c:\users\me\documents. Manually excluding subdirs to c:\users\me\documents except visual studio 2015\projects is sub-optimal because I'd have to constantly patrol the parent dir - for instance, if I install a new program, the odds are good it will create a new subdir, which would then get backed up.

Comment: Still a bit confused. Is your situation that when you exclude the whole folder you cannot then add sub-folders, which is what you are trying now and doesn't work? A wild idea: Exclude everything, setup a new folder that contains symlinks to the folders you want backed up, then backup that folder. You will need to do the testing, because I avoid File History and use a backup program instead.

Comment: superuser is complaining about extended discussion in comments, but I'm relatively new so please point this in a different direction if need be. The answer to your question is Yes. The suggestion to use a link is grea; I used mklink /d, but the actual path is inserted in the XML file, so back to square 0.

Comment: One last idea before I suggest to abandon File History : Use the [subst command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) to give the symlinks folder a drive-letter, or make it a network share and mount it.

Comment: No dice. In both cases, I get "Sorry but that didn't work..." with code 0x800732. There was a nice file backup feature in Win7 that I was trying to replicate. I do regular backups, but being able to pick a version of an individual file from the Properties dialog was very convenient! Guess I'll have to include the parent dir and exclude all the ones I don't want for now.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I decided to type my own script in powershell. I do not understand, why do I have to exclude files from File History when I would have to have the option of selecting which folders I want to backup. Microsoft selects a long list of folders, when I tried to exclude the folders I didn't want to backup, I would need 2 days for that.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer and either post your script or a link to it on Github? It could be useful to others.